# Editing Multiple Things With Hover Property CSS

Tags: css

So I'm trying to edit elements in my div when the div is hovered over, using pure CSS. What I have now is below.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
div{
background-color:blue;
border-radius:5px;
width:50px;
height:60px;
transition:width 2s;
-moz-transition:width 2s;
-webkit-transition:width 2s;

}
p.op{
opacity:0.0;
transition:opacity 2s;
-moz-transition:opacity 2s;
-webkit-transition:opacity 2s;

}

div:hover{
width:120px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<p class="op">Hello World</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm wondering how to edit the opacity of the text on the hover of the div, such that the text would turn from invisible to visible as the div expands. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
div:hover p.op
{
  opacity:1;
}
```

***Live Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ypzxk/1/*

---

Demo also contains a few changes to your CSS so that the text is clearer for the example, and the text doesn't wrap when the `div` is too short in width:

```
div{
background-color:blue;
border-radius:5px;
width:50px;
height:60px;
transition:width 2s;
-moz-transition:width 2s;
-webkit-transition:width 2s;
overflow:hidden;
}
p.op{
opacity:0.0;
color:#fff; 
transition:opacity 2s;
-moz-transition:opacity 2s;
-webkit-transition:opacity 2s;
width:120px;
}

div:hover{
width:120px;
}

div:hover p.op
{
  opacity:1;
}
```